# Android ImageView with scaleType matrix not applying matrix to background resource

Tags: android, imageview, transformation

I have an ImageView which I apply a transformation matrix too. The same `ImageView` also has a frame background (a nine patch drawable, assigned with `setBackgroundResource`) but the background just stays the original size and position while the image is transformed correctly (scale, rotation and translate).

What is the correct way to make the background transform the same way as the image?

`AdjustViewBounds` didn't make any difference.

Comment: The matrix doesn't apply to the background-  backgrounds are drawn as is.  You'll need to d some work of your own to get it to apply to both-  possibly making a layer drawable out of them and setting it as a single image resource.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Is it possible to change an image resources in the layer drawable? my image is being updated constantly. The background stays the same (just the frame).

Comment: Managed to get this working with the layer list. With a negative <inset> the frame sits nicely around the main image. Thanks Gabe Sechan